# Hibernate - OneToMany Relation

Tags: hibernate

Shall we put the entry of an attribute in `toString()` method of a Hibernate model class if it is lazy loaded and is used in OneToMany relationship?

```
class Employee {
    private Set<IiopUrl.Address> addressDetailsSet;
    //getters and setters

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @JoinTable(name = "Employee_Address_Map",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Employee_ID", referencedColumnName = "INNER_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Address_Id", referencedColumnName = "INNER_ID")},
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"Employee_ID", Address_Id}))
    public Set<IiopUrl.Address> getAddressDetailsSet() {
        return addressDetailsSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code mentioned is a sample code. Please don't bother for signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may expect, the answer is "it depends".  There will surely be case that you may need to rely on `toString()`  in your logic which will need to include the relationships.

However, in most case, including such attributes are going to cause problem.  `toString()` are usually used in different diagnostic situations (e.g. in logging, during debugging etc), including relationships may run into the following problem:

1. If you call `toString()` outside transaction boundary, runtime exception will be thrown because of there is no session (in Hibernate's term) for lazy fetching.
2. Given that entities are usually linked up in relationships which can form a huge object graph, if you blindly include relationships in your `toString()`, you will turn out fetching a huge amount of data, which can cause a lot of problem.

My personal experience is I would only includes relationship that is closely related.  I would rather excluding the relationship if I am not sure if it is really needed.  Keep `toString()` merely for diagnostic purpose, and if you need String representation in your business logic, consider declaring a new method and interface for such purpose.